# Running lua scripts on arduino ssh command shell

Tags: linux, ssh, lua, arduino, intel-galileo

I have Intel Galileo board .
I have inserted to it SD card with Linux image so I could connect to it with putty ssh.
Now I can  run Linux commands on the device itself with putty.

I want to know how i can make led blink using 
lua script , I want to execute the script on the device (in putty command line).

how do i do that ??

Answer (score 1):

Just has you would do on a normal shell: `lua -i` will launch lua in interactive mode, that mean you can input code line by line and the interpreter will execute it.

Another possibility is us `scp`, this will use the SSH connection to move file, like a FTP but it will just work over any SSH connection by default